# How can I find/replace instances of double hyphens (--) with triple hypens (---) in vim?

Tags: vim, regex

I know there's probably a way to do that using regex, but I can't quite seem to figure out regex in vim. I tried searching: `/-\{2}` but it catches triple hyphens, too.

I also can't just do a traditional find and replace, since I have triple hyphens in my file. Searching for `--` returns triple hyphens in addition to double hyphens.

Comment: Did you try `:%s/--/---/g`? It works for me.

Comment: I should have said that my file also contains triple hyphens, so if I do that, I would get triple hyphens turning into quadruple hyphens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about `:%s,-\@<!---\@!,---,g`? That way it won't change '---' to '----'.

Comment: That works, thanks! I don't understand how, but I'll go look up what commas and @ symbols mean in vim.

Comment: @Jon The comma is a delimiter—whatever character immediately follows it is used to separate the search expression, the replace expression, and any options (in this case `g`). (Usually `/` is used, but it's not so nice to look at when you have lots of backslashes.) The `-\@<!` prevents the pattern from matching immediately after a '-', and the `-\@!' keeps it from matching immediately before a '-'.

Answer (score 2):

Your example works for me, so I suspect you have a different character in your file that only looks like a hyphen.

I would suggest placing your cursor on one in normal mode, typing `yl` to yank the character, then typing / followed by pressing control-r then " (double quote).  If that works, you can use the same trick to create your substitute command.

Comment: I should have said above that my example, while it returns double hyphens, also returns triple hyphens, and so if I were to do a find/replace using that example, it would turn all my triple hyphens into quadruple hyphens, which is not what I want. But thanks very much for the `yl`, /, ctrl-r, " trick--I didn't know that one, and that's going to solve a lot of other problems for me.